# Why Grails ignores the HTTP Accept header by default?

Tags: rest, grails, groovy

From the Grails documentation ..

> Grails ignores the HTTP Accept header unless you add a grails.mime.use.accept.header = true setting to your Config.groovy file. In other words, withFormat() will be completely unaffected by the Accept header without that setting

Why this choice was made​​ ? Is there any concern about using the Accept header, such way that Grails by default only interprets the format parameter ??

What's the pro and cons of specify the communication medium with the format parameter or the Accept header in the REST architecture ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some older browsers send either invalid accept headers or `*/*` which isn't helpful so Grails can default to use the Accept header because otherwise on some browsers XML or JSON is sent back instead of HTML inside a browser. Having said this behaviour has changed in more recent versions of Grails.

In more recent versions of Grails (since 2.3.0) the `ACCEPT` header *is enabled* by default, but ignored for certain `USER-AGENT` strings (i.e. browsers)

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-resources/src/grails/grails-app/conf/Config.groovy#L17